# Run heroku-cli command in heroku-based application

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I'm trying to delete heroku application from another heroku web-appication
There is a bash-script: `heroku apps:destroy ${APP_NAME} --confirm ${APP_NAME}`
Locally it works fine because I have installed heroku-toolbelt; but on heroku-server I get an error: 'heroku: not found'

Is it possible to work with heroku-cli from heroku-based apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the heroku toolbelt buildpack, which provides the toolbelt alongside your application:

- https://github.com/gregburek/heroku-buildpack-toolbelt

You can also use the heroku API directly from your app:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/platform-api

Comment: Thank you! I found heroku-client library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/heroku-client Works perfect